# ModalPopupExtender Hault Execution Until Ok is Clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

Perhaps I misunderstood the control, or very possibly am not implementing it correctly, but I've used a ModalPopupExtender much like I'd like to use a MessageBox in desktop development.  The problem I'm running into is that once I call the Show() method of the ModalPopupExtender it continues to execute the server side code despite the fact that the user has not yet clicked the button set as the OkControlID.  Is this the normal behavior, and or is there a way to hault code execution until the OkControlID has been clicked.  To specify, I don't want to create another event in the button click handler as this popup is inline.  Here is my code - any advice is appreciated.

My Control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ModalMessage.ascx.cs" Inherits="LB.ModalMessage" %>
<asp:Button ID="btnPopup" runat="server" style="display: none;"/>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalMessageExtender" runat="server"
OkControlID="btnOkay" PopupControlID="Panel1"
TargetControlID="btnPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalPopupBG">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel CssClass="whitebubble" ID="Panel1" style="display: none; max-width:400px;" runat="server">
<div style="padding:5px 5px 35px 5px;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" Font-Size="Medium" runat="server" ForeColor="Black"/>
    <br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Ok" Width="75px" Height="30px" ID="btnOkay" CssClass="modalButton gray modalButton"/>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

The control code behind:

```
    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        this.lblMessage.Text = message;
        ModalMessageExtender.Show();
    }
```

My content page:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/ModalMessage.ascx" TagName="ModalMessage" TagPrefix="mm" %>
<mm:ModalMessage runat="server" ID="mpeMessage"/>
```

My content code behind:

```
mpeMessage.ShowMessage("Please enter a username before attempting to reset your password.");
```

**UPDATE:**
Sorry for the lack of clarity - let me make my question more clear.  If I do the following:

```
mpeMessage.ShowMessage("Please enter a username before attempting to reset your password.");
Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
```

The redirect occurs and the ModalPopupExtender never gets shown.  I'm somewhat new to web development so please forgive me if I'm using incorrect terminology.  But essentially, I want the execution of code in the code behinds to wait for the user to click "Ok".  I'm trying to replace something like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Message", "alert('Your new account has been created!'); window.location='" + continueUrl + "';", true);
```

With something a little nicer looking, and since I'm already doing a postback anyway, I thought calling the ModalPopupExtender programmatically would be fine.  Hopefully this clears up my question.  Thank you all for your responses so far.

Comment: Can you clairfy what you mean by "Server Side Code Continues to run"? Serverside code will continue to run until the page is sent to the browser. It appears you are wanting to trigger the extender Server Side. The page will complete it's life cycle as per normal. If you were to halt this the page would never be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation controls , to check whether the fields are properly filled or not
for more details check the following links:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refvalidationcontrols.asp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx

Comment: Not sure what validation controls have to do with the issue?  Perhaps I'm just not clear on what you're suggesting.  I am validating my controls, but the above code occurs on a postback after that's already happened.  I'm trying to determine how to make the ModalPopupExtender more like a JavaScript "Alert".  Hopefully that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding your query correctly then you want that until user does not click on "ok" button on modelpopup, user should not be able to click on page.

if you want this then add **PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel1"** in your modelpopup control.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalMessageExtender" runat="server"
OkControlID="btnOkay" PopupControlID="Panel1" PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel1"
TargetControlID="btnPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalPopupBG">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

**UPDATE**

just replace **Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");** to *btnOkay* click event.

on aspx page -

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Ok" Width="75px" Height="30px" ID="btnOkay"  OnClick="btnOkay_Click" CssClass="modalButton gray modalButton"/>
```

on aspx.cs page -

```
protected void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
}
```

then until user will not click on "Ok" button. he/she can't redirect to Register Page.

Comment: I thought this was only to allow for the modal to be moved around?  I don't see that there was a change when doing this, can you please provide an example based on my update above.  Thank you.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing until I can come up with a better solution, but it's not a solve for the problem...I want to be able to call the show method inline like an alert regardless of what the following code is and have it halt code execution until the user clicks ok.

Comment: Perhaps a better explanation would be a "MessageBox.Show()" equivalent from desktop development...same concept.  I realize there's a confirmation extender, but it only works on button click, so I don't think that's all that spectacular of an option either :-\